# This keyboard won't leave

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I'm having a weird behavior from a keyboard. But only on one of the view controllers. I have another view controller with a UITextField and that one works charms (as soon as I press the return button it disappears). And the weird part is that that one isnt even setup at all. it only has becomefirstresponder on viewdidload and resignfirstresponder on viewwilldissapear.
THIS keyboard however, [VIDEO OF NASTY KEYBOARD](https://youtu.be/oDmRC66BWCQ) is quite the nasty booger.
NOTE: In the video I do the following:
* Tap the UITextfield
* Keyboard Appears (view shifts up)
* I type lol and then press send (nothing happens)
* I start tapping frantically all around the screen (except the UITextField)
* Keyboard dissapears

Here's the code for this View:

```
class ChatScreenVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var gameDelegate: GameManagerDelegate?
    var chatLogString: String = ""
    var offsetY:CGFloat = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var chatView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var closeBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleBtn: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var chatLog: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var chatInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sendBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBAction func inputTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        chatInput.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func closeTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func sendTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if chatInput.text != nil && chatInput.text != "" && chatInput.text != " " {
            gameDelegate?.sendChat(message: chatInput.text!)
        }
        chatInput.text = ""
        chatInput.resignFirstResponder()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
            viewCenterConstraint.constant = -keyboardHeight
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("THIS IS HAPPENING!")
        chatInput.resignFirstResponder()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            viewCenterConstraint.constant = 0
        }
    }

    @objc func reloadData() {
        chatLogString = (gameDelegate?.updateChatString())!
        chatLog.text = chatLogString
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        chatLog.text = chatLogString
        chatLog.isEditable = false
        chatInput.autocorrectionType = .no
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setupView()
        animateView()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        chatInput.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reloadData), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: SMACK_TALK), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name(rawValue: SMACK_TALK), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    }

}
```

Now before you go and tell me "not to use both the resignfirstresponder and the endediting(true)" I gotta clear out that I tried both individually and together and still don't get any response.

Comment: Pretty sure you should be returning false in `textFieldShouldReturn(_:)`.  Give that a shot.

Comment: Can you just add first line chatInput.resignFirstResponder() on sendTapped(_ sender: Any).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. None of them seemed to have changed anything as far as the behavior of the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can resign keyboard before `sendChat()`. I think it is sync call and it will block main thread for sometimes thats why this weird behaviour occurs.

`chatInput.resignFirstResponder()` before you are making API call.

```
@IBAction func sendTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if chatInput.text != nil && chatInput.text != "" && chatInput.text != " " {
        chatInput.resignFirstResponder()
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        gameDelegate?.sendChat(message: chatInput.text!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it doesn't work. I even tried adding it like `sendTapped() {chatInput.resignFirstResponer()  DispatchQueue.main.async{update chat Log}` AND EVEN `DispatchQueue.main.AsyncAfter(.now() + 0.25 {update Chat Log})` however the behavior is still the same as in the video